# 405 Method Not Allowed When Redirecting in Flask within POST route

Tags: python, flask, redirect, http-status-code-405

I'm hoping to shed some light on why I am getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

**Expected Outcome** - User should be redirected to manage.html template when they attempt to add a review to a game they have already added a review to.

**Actual Outcome** - 405 Error (Method Not Allowed) Displayed.

**Manage Route**:

```
@app.route('/manage')
def manage():
    """Renders manage.html template."""
    return render_template('manage.html')
```

**Submit Review Route**:

```
@app.route('/submit_review/<game_id>', methods=['POST'])
def submit_review(game_id):
    """
    Add users review to database.
    """
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()
    existing_review = Review.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id,
                                             game_id=game.id).first()

    if existing_review:
        flash('You have already created a review for this game')
        return redirect(url_for('manage'))
...
```

**What I Have Tried**:
I've done some reading of the flask documentation, specifically around `flask.redirect` ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.redirect)), and searched for other examples, but I have been unable to find something that resolves my issue.

I have a hunch that when the user submits the form, and they have already have a review for that particular game, the POST request is also being redirected to the "manage" route.

I checked the network tab in dev tools and it is a GET request, which is correct for that URL.

I guess what I'm trying to say is... I have no idea why this is happening, so don't know how to search for a resolution.

**Screenshot of Network -> Headers tab in dev tools**:
[image: Screenshot of Network -> Headers tab in dev tools]

**Server Console**:

```
[10/May/2022 18:43:49] "POST /submit_review/11198 HTTP/1.1" 302 -

[10/May/2022 18:43:49] "review-rating=0&review-heading=&liked-text=&disliked-text=&review-hours=1&game-name=Rocket+League&igdb-id=&igdb-summary=&igdb-cover-url=&action=GET /manage HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Comment: What do you get in the server console?

Comment: @Fredericka I have edited post to include what is in the console

Comment: What do you do if there isn't an existing review?

Comment: @Henry the review is added to the database. I didn't include as was not relevant to the question.

Comment: Do you do any redirect after adding it to the database?

Comment: @Henry Yes, If the user has not already created a review for that particular game, the review is stored in the database, and the user is redirected to the home page. On the home page there is a list of all the reviews every user has created, the redirect completes without error. The list of reviews has not yet been implemented, but currently has place holders hard coded.

Comment: Does `redirect(url_for('manage', None))` work?

Comment: I get something different...
Page displays Redirecting...
`You should be redirected automatically to target URL: /manage. If not click the link.`

Does not proceed to /manage unless I click the link. 
Clicking link loads the /manage route correctly, and displays the flash message.

Comment: That's strange. The [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) for `url_for` say "Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments." which seems to be what is happening here. Passing `None` seems to avoid this, but I'm not sure why you're getting the redirect message.

Comment: @Henry I apologise, I miss-read your code
`redirect(url_for('manage', None))` produces error: `TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
What I did:
`redirect(url_for('manage'), None)` produces as per my previous comment

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then.

Comment: So I have a "fix" because of what you mentioned above... "Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments."

The form data is processed if the `existing_review == None` - therefore if the `existing_review != None` the function returns before the form data gets used. Meaning the "Variable Arguments" are unknown to the target endpoint, in this case the `/manage` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, Thank you @Henry for the inspiration to finding a solution.

**Secondly**, I have learnt that including the entire function in the original question, and not just what I feel may be relevant, may have resolved this much sooner.

**The Answer**.

@Henry mentioned that as per the docs for `url_for()` - "Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments."

This is my take on the situation.

The `submit_review()` function was returning before the form data was being used, meaning that the form data was unknown to the target endpoint.

**Function Before Fix**:

```
@app.route('/submit_review/<game_id>', methods=['POST'])
def submit_review(game_id):
    """
    Adds users review to database.
    """

    existing_game = Game.query.filter_by(igdb_id=game_id).first()

    if not existing_game:
        igdb_game_data = get_game_data_by_id(game_id)[0]
        igdb_game_artwork = get_game_artwork(game_id)
        igdb_game_cover = get_game_cover_art(game_id)

        game = Game(
            name=igdb_game_data['name'],
            artwork=json.dumps(igdb_game_artwork),
            summary=igdb_game_data['summary'],
            igdb_id=igdb_game_data['id'],
            cover_art=igdb_game_cover
        )

        db.session.add(game)
        db.session.commit()

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()
    game = Game.query.filter_by(igdb_id=game_id).first()

    existing_review = Review.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id,
                                             game_id=game.id).first()

    if existing_review:
        print(request)
        flash('You have already created a review for this game')
        return redirect(url_for('manage'))

    review = Review(
        user_id=user.id,
        game_id=game.id,
        rating=float(request.form.get('review-rating')),
        heading=request.form.get('review-heading'),
        liked_text=request.form.get('liked-text'),
        disliked_text=request.form.get('disliked-text'),
        hours=int(request.form.get('review-hours')),
    )

    db.session.add(review)
    db.session.commit()

    flash('Review added successfully')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

By moving where the form data is used, I got the expected results, functionality is correct, as the review is not added to the database if a review for that game, by the same user is present.

**Function After Fix**:

```
@app.route('/submit_review/<game_id>', methods=['POST'])
def submit_review(game_id):
    """
    Adds users review to database.
    """

    existing_game = Game.query.filter_by(igdb_id=game_id).first()

    if not existing_game:
        igdb_game_data = get_game_data_by_id(game_id)[0]
        igdb_game_artwork = get_game_artwork(game_id)
        igdb_game_cover = get_game_cover_art(game_id)

        game = Game(
            name=igdb_game_data['name'],
            artwork=json.dumps(igdb_game_artwork),
            summary=igdb_game_data['summary'],
            igdb_id=igdb_game_data['id'],
            cover_art=igdb_game_cover
        )

        db.session.add(game)
        db.session.commit()

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()
    game = Game.query.filter_by(igdb_id=game_id).first()

    existing_review = Review.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id,
                                             game_id=game.id).first()

    review = Review(
        user_id=user.id,
        game_id=game.id,
        rating=float(request.form.get('review-rating')),
        heading=request.form.get('review-heading'),
        liked_text=request.form.get('liked-text'),
        disliked_text=request.form.get('disliked-text'),
        hours=int(request.form.get('review-hours')),
    )

    if existing_review:
        print(request)
        flash('You have already created a review for this game')
        return redirect(url_for('manage'))

    db.session.add(review)
    db.session.commit()

    flash('Review added successfully')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the review the method is POST. Then you redirect to the page /manage that does not accept POST. The request is still POST causing an error. Try adding the POST method to your /manage decorator.

```
@app.route('/manage', methods= ["GET", "POST"])
def manage():
    """Renders manage.html template."""
    return render_template('manage.html')
```

As i can see in your console, your form uses the GET request? In this case you can use something like

```
redirect("/Whereever", code=307)
```

Comment: I updated code as suggested, no change in result.

Comment: Try the second solution, because you form is set to use GET methods

Comment: `<form class="col s12" action="{{url_for('submit_review', game_id=data.id)}}" method='POST'>` the form is set to use POST, I don't understand why console says GET.

Comment: Updated redirect to `return redirect(url_for('manage'), code=307)` only change in the result is that Status code in devtools for "11198" has changed to "307 Temporary Redirect"